# Time Machine won't let me use volume

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, sparsebundle

I put an 8TB external drive on a Mac Mini (5,3) running Mojave (10.14.6). This machine is named "Data". I then made a Time Machine Backup on that drive.

I made that Mini a backup server, by selecting it in System Preferences —> Sharing —> File Sharing, then using Control-Click on the 8TB drive to see the hidden menu, picking "Advanced Options", and clicking "Share as a Time Machine backup destination."

I then began backing up two other machines to this drive, "Create", and "Web".

The local backup finished, an hour went by, and Time Machine tried to do a second backup, but halted with the message:
`Would you like this computer to inherit the backup history from “Web” on the “8TB” backup disk? The backup was created on a different computer. If you inherit this backup, it can no longer be used by the original computer.`

That dialogue has three buttons: "Don't Back Up Now", "Create New Backup", and "Inherit Backup History". I don't want **any** of those options!

The drive "8TB" has the following root level contents, as expected: folder "Backups.backupdb", and two disk images, "Create.sparsebundle" and "Web.sparsebundle".

So, what do I do? I obviously don't want to use the "Web" machine backup on the "Data" machine, but it seemingly doesn't understand it has its **own** backup.

**UPDATE:** "Create" is still running its base backup, so I don't want to do anything to disturb that. So on the machine physically connected to the backup disk (Data), I chose "Create New Backup" on the popup, and it successfully did an incremental backup!

So I waited an hour, and the same annoying popup happened. I chose "Create New Backup" again, and it created another incremental backup.

I logged out and closed Screen Sharing and left it overnight, and no new backups appeared — which is wrong, as this is a MySQL server driving a public-facing website, and I'm certain at least some of the MySQL table files had changed. (Logs confirm that.)

I logged in to Data, opened the Time Machine System Preference, waited for the next backup to happen, and then got the same stupid dialogue.

Surely, there's some .plist or system default or something I can change to get rid of this **STUPID, USELESS** dialogue? I want automatic backups without having to click "Create New Backup" every time!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why such behavior is occurring, but splitting the drive into 2 volumes should almost definitely fix the issue (with almost no drawbacks due to how APFS splits volumes). To fix this issue, use disk utility to add another volume to the APFS container (this has the advantage that, unlike a partition, division of space flexible). Then share both of these and use one volume per computer.

Comment: I can't use APFS on this disk, because it needs to also work on a much older machine that can't even see APFS volumes.

Comment: @JanSteinman You need at least one APFS partition if the other machine is Big Sur (doesn't work with HFS+). So partition the disk into an HFS+ (MacOS Journaled) partition and APFS partition (If you have no big sur machines, this can be HFS too). But here, you must estimate how much each backup is and create a non-flexible distribution.

Comment: All machines being backed up to this disk are Mojave. I would like to avoid re-formatting and re-backing up if at all possible. The machine hosting the backup drive (Data) already did a full backup! I just want to be able to use it! A second machine (Web) has completed the base backup and several incrementals. The biggest machine (Create) is still only about a quarter of the way through its base backup. I'd hate to abandon all that by re-formatting! It seems to be working… almost!

Comment: @JanSteinman Maybe the bug went away, in that case. Maybe if you wait a week it will fix itself. Others may have ideas too.

Comment: Bug did not go away. I can get around it by clicking "Create New Backup". But this is a headless, unattended machine — I don't want to have to fire up Screen Sharing and click a dialogue every time I want a backup!

Answer (score 0):

This didn't come up on my first search here, but I found a tour-de-force for problems associating backups, devices, and hosts: [Inheriting Time Machine Backup: Invalid Target](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375894/inheriting-time-machine-backup-invalid-target?rq=1)

In reading that, I realized that I had done a brain-transplant on this machine when another Mac Mini died. The dead one was my database server, and the one I moved the hard disk to was "Web." According to [1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375894/inheriting-time-machine-backup-invalid-target?rq=1), backups are associated with MAC addresses on machines, so of course, for the purpose of backup, this machine thinks it is "Web" and so insists on using the existing backups for Web.

I haven't yet solved the problem, with with the help of [1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375894/inheriting-time-machine-backup-invalid-target?rq=1), I think I know how to do so. It involves editing /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist to change the association between MAC address ("HostUUID")and the proper backup location.

AAARRRGGGHHH!!! I wish Apple had given us some tools for managing this stuff!