# Inheriting Time Machine Backup

Tags: time-machine

I am having issues inheriting my old TM back up from my old MBP when I upgraded to my new MBP. Apple TM engineers had no answer and merely said it was a loss. When attempting to inherit I get the following error:

`Failed to inherit machine store at '(null)', error: Error Domain=TMStructureErrorDomain Code=7 "Structure has wrong type" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Structure has wrong type}`

When attempting to associate disk I get the following error:

`Usage: tmutil associatedisk [-a] mount_point volume_backup_directory A local volume mount point and a snapshot volume path are required.`

I found the answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/376109/449546) though the answer is well over my head and I sadly do not have the reputation to comment yet and ask for further assistance, hence me starting a nearly identical question. So I apologize about that. If anyone or even the original responder (klanomath) would be able to guide me thorough it I would greatly appreciate it. I am comfortable using terminal but more on a copy and paste command lines as instructed basis not so much creating my own commands with the exception of some minor sifting through folders.

Thanks an advanced for any help!